# How to run angular and angular js framework in a single project

Tags: angular

Is their any way such that we can run both framework i.e angular and angular js in a single project, so that few of the existing module runs on the angular js framework and new modules in new framework i.e angular. And have association between both the frame work.

Comment: Take a look at this, may help https://github.com/nelsonomuto/angular-multi-version-example

Answer (score 0):

you could run them parellel from official document [Upgrading from AngularJS to Angular](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade), this will make your project bundle bigger with both framework

Or you could fake the syntax if your project is small enough by changing the syntax and then remove angularjs with angular core following this link [ng-forward](https://github.com/ngUpgraders/ng-forward/blob/master/Walkthrough.md), this will make your project remain the same size + the parsing syntax library, but the core is still angularjs